# Mapping an array of data into one table row using fpdf library

Tags: codeigniter

I have some trouble in using fpdf library in codeigniter. I have a function that will export all the data into pdf file. But a have a problem mapping the data into a table row.

What I want to do is this

```
Name        | Short_Name | Active | Destinations
Sample Name | SN         | true   | Destination 1, Destination 2, Destination 3,
```

But I only ended up getting this

```
Name        | Short_Name | Active | Destinations
Sample Name | SN         | true   | Destination 3,
```

I cant map the whole data. I always get one data only.

So far, this is the code structure that I have worked on.

```
$data = $this->airlines->get_airline($id);
$airlineloc = $this->destinations->get_airline_location($id);
$location = $this->destinations->get_active_destination(); //location

// The mapping of the data 
foreach($data as $row) {

    $destinations = [];

        $this->destinationperairline->Cell($w[0], 8, $row->LongName,'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->destinationperairline->Cell($w[1], 8, $row->ShortName, 'LR', 0, 'C', $fill);


        if($row->Active == 1){
            $this->destinationperairline->Cell($w[2], 8, 'Active', 'LR', 0, 'C', $fill);
        }

        // Mapping the locations  
        foreach($location as $row4) {
            // Mapping the locations to its specific airline 
            foreach($airlineloc as $row3) {
                // This codeblock should map the whole data in the pdf table row
                if($row3->ChildID == $row4->DictionaryID && $row->Active == 1) {
                    $destinations = $row4->LongName.",";
                }

            }

        }

        $this->destinationperairline->Cell($w[3], 8, $destinations, 'LR', 0, 'C', $fill);

        $this->destinationperairline->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
}
```

Is there any way I can map the whole data in a single table row using the fpdf library? Thanks to all who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `concatenate` the data by using `.=` instead of `=`. When you use `=` it overwrites previous values and only the last value is left. Also, you don't need `$destinations = [];`

```
// $destinations = []; // remove this
// ...
// ...
// ...
if($row3->ChildID == $row4->DictionaryID && $row->Active == 1) {
    $destinations .= $row4->LongName.","; // change here
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Dude, your a blessing. I also learned something. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: Happy to help. :)